# how to manage complicated array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have:

```
return data:
array ( 0 => 'test' )array ( 0 => 'test Drink', 1 => 'Chi' )
```

I want to split this return data into two arrays:

- `$arrFood`, has one element: `'test'`
- `$arrDrink`, has two elements: `'test Drink'` and `'Chi'`.

How can that be done?

Comment: Is the return data a string?

Comment: You should return an array of objects with properties like `"type" : "drink", "name" : "Chi"` that way you can tell the difference between a food and a drink...

Comment: Yes, the return data as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you just want to create 2 arrays from a given return which is two arrays, so you can do this:

```
function Array(arr, arr2){
   $arrFood = arr;
   $arrDrink = arr2;
}
```

This link can show you a little more about Arrays:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: It's actually the data returned from AJAX as a string and I need to assign the two arrays into different variables

Comment: So you split the array with the word 'array' and look for words between ' (comma) and add to your array